Pyinstaller: Spec File Not Found
Pyinstaller is unable to locate my spec file to build my application.
This error occurs:
E:\Hqtools\scan-certyify\app>CALL ..\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
1923 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.9.0, contrib hooks: 2024.7
1923 INFO: Python: 3.12.4
1974 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22000-SP0
1975 INFO: Python environment: C:\Users\V61BSSS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
2639 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\V61BSSS\AppData\Local\pyinstaller
Spec file ".\main.spec" not found!

The main.spec is located in the correct folder. I'm not sure what could be causing the build bat to not find the spec file.

Please add more information and what you tried to solve the problem. Why are you sure that "The main.spec is located in the correct folder"?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
